# bootstrap popovers won't display in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular-cli

I'm using bootstrap 5.0.0-beta2 and I'm trying to implement it in angular 11.2.1.

1. I used npm to download bootsrap
2. I added node_modules path to bootsrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.bundle.js to angular.json styles and scripts

the bootstrap CSS works fine, and I tried to create a dismissing alert who also works and make me believe that boostrap js is working too.

but my issues comes with the popovers:

here's how I tried to implement them

- I created a component `test bootsrap`
- and a js folder in assets

here is my component HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="right"
        data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Popover on right
</button>
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those fields below.
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
```

and here's my component TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-popovers',
  templateUrl: './popovers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./popovers.component.css']
})
export class PopoversComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadscript('./assets/js/popovers.js');
  }

  loadscript(path: string): void {
    const s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = path;
    s.async = false;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
  }
}
```

here I am trying to call for a JS script enabling the popovers

popovers.js:

```js
var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'));
var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
});
console.log(popoverList);
```

now here's my issue once I run my angular app with `ng serve` and connect to localhost:4200 I see my working alert and a bootstrap button but when I click on it nothing happens, even if my console does log the popoversList.

[image]

does someone know where this might come from and how I could solve this ?

Comment: wouldn't it be much easier to use [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home)?

Comment: I recreated a minimal example and it says `bootstrap is not defined`. However i was able to use `$('#test').popover('show')` to enable the popover (after adding `test` id to the button). Do you have a repro? I agree with @vitaliykotov that you should user ng-bootstrap, unles it's strictly necessary not to.

Comment: I was said that under bootstrap 5.0.0 jquery were used and I often had conflict issues with jquery and angular-cli, also is ng-bootstrap complete, like does it hafe the same component than common bootstrap and does it have the same conflict risk with jquery ? @AlexCazacu

Comment: Their website says they use only Bootstrap CSS and angular, do i would assume you are pretty safe. They offer all the same widgets + some new ones like datepicker, rating, typeahead. However it uses bootstrap 4.5

Comment: why are you using the ts file to create a script element to pull in js? Just write the js in the ts file, that's the entire point of it! I imagine somewhere in there is where your problem is. In your template button add in a (click)="doTheThing()" and doTheThing() in the ts component file.

Comment: in typescript I didn't knew how to import bootstrao in the ts file @andrewf

Comment: you should be able to add the necessary js and css files in your angular.json file